# MySQL Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt some fields on `MySQL`. I'm using the `v2.8` version of `TPC-DS` and I'm trying to use `AES` on some columns of Customer Address table. Any idea how you can encrypt all the rows of the fields? I tried to use

```sql
UPDATE customer SET c_first_name = AES_ENCRYPT(c_first_name, key)
```

but I'm getting an error saying the `Data too long for column c_first_name at row 1`

Comment: What type does `c_first_name` have?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the customer first name. Do I have to alter the numer of char before (varchar(12) to varchar(200) for exemple)?

Comment: That number is the size of the column. If you want more than 12 bytes, yes, you need to increase it.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the data on field level at all? It does not provide the protection you think it would, but will mess with your database operations.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html) recommends storing encrypted values in VARBINARY and BLOB type columns and also gives the following for calculating the required column size when using AES_ENCRYPT().

> 16 * (trunc(string_length / 16) + 1)

'string_length' is the bytes required to store the string, not the number of characters, which is dependent on the CHARACTER SET you are using. You'll get this information as `character_octet_length` in `information_schema`.`columns`

If you are using utf8mb4 as your character set, then your VARCHAR(12) `c_first_name` column would have character_octet_length of 48 and you would require VARBINARY(64) to accommodate any possible value.

```
mysql> SELECT 16 * (TRUNCATE(48 / 16, 0) + 1);
+---------------------------------+
| 16 * (TRUNCATE(48 / 16, 0) + 1) |
+---------------------------------+
|                              64 |
+---------------------------------+
```

e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH(AES_ENCRYPT(_utf8mb4'','salt')) AS v arbinary_length;
+------------------+
| varbinary_length |
+------------------+
|               64 |
+------------------+
```

You can use this to get the required VARBINARY column sizes for the customer table

```
SELECT `column_name`, `character_set_name`, `column_type`, `character_octet_length`,
16 * (TRUNCATE(`character_octet_length` / 16, 0) + 1) AS varbinary_size
FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE `table_name` = 'customer';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way

```
alter table customer modify c_first_name varbinary(200);
update customer 
set c_first_name = aes_encrypt(c_first_name , 'secretyKey');
```

Comment: Yes thats what I thought. Thank you!